# CakePHP: How to use a function with a model in every controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, shibboleth

I have a project which includes **admin** and **user** section. Both section use the same controllers, just different functions and templates (ex: `viewAdmin()` and `viewUser()`). In function `beforeRender()` of every controllers, I set variable `$admin` as `true` for admin functions and `false` for user functions.

For authentication, I use **Shibboleth**. Shibboleth uses data from LDAP, while user types were saved in SQL-Database, that means while it can check if the login and password are false, it can't check if the user is admin or not. An user can go to ADMIN section as long as they use the right `action` (ex: go to the link http://example.com/tool/viewAdmin).

To prevent this, I will have to:

1. Load model `Users`
2. Compare the environment variable `uid` (login name) with the "login" columns in `Users` table in my SQL-Database
3. See the "type" column in `Users` table to know if user is admin or not.
4. Compare the result with value of `$admin` and redirect to an error page when necessary.

The problem is: I don't want to repeat those steps for EVERY controllers.

Currently I have 2 ideas:

1. Write a function in `UsersController`, and use it in every controllers.
2. Create a component and load it in every controllers.

Both methods require me changing code in all controllers. I would like to hear a better way with less work, perhaps by changing `app.php` or `bootstrap.php`.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Write a component that does everything internally, via beforeFilter() callback, this way you can hook this in globally once in AppController. See how [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) handles this smartly.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did think of writing a component and using in AppController, however, my variable `$admin`  would be undefined. To compare with `$admin`, I would have to personally load that component in every controller. I read about your suggested plugin, but it seems to filter user type based on **AuthComponent**, while my project used **Shibboleth**.

Answer (score 0):

To share methods in CakePHP controllers you can do:

1. Create component and include in controller
2. Or create method in AppController and use it in child controllers
3. Or PHP way create Trait.

But when you authorize users, then all user data is stored in session, incl. is user roles (example admin, regular, member,.. )

Comment: I had already thought of creating a component, the true problem is I don't want to repeat loading this component in EVERY controller. Creating method in AppController or Trait served the same idea as component.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official CakePHP authentication plugin and extend the LDAP adapter with the additional code check you need. This is very easy to do and also a very clean way of solving the problem. Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the authentication plugin. https://github.com/cakephp/authentication

Or if you want to stay agnostic to any framework, use my library that is based on the authentication plugin and was decoupled from any framework but still works just nice with Cake https://github.com/Phauthentic/authentication.

Comment: The documentation linked to Cookbook with CakePHP version 1.1 so I was quite reluctant to use it.

Comment: 1.1 is the version of the plugin, not the framework.

Comment: For the past day I had tried to implement this plugin with Shibboleth login page which I had, unfortunately, zero knowledges. I think it's faster for me to just filter user type in every controllers after all. Thanks for the help anyway.